# Read file in non-blocking mode on Linux

Tags: c, linux, random, file-io, posix

When opening the file /dev/urandom in nonblocking mode it is still blocking when reading. Why is the read call still blocking.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("Unable to open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    if (flags & O_NONBLOCK) {
        printf("non block is set\n");
    }

    int ret;
    char* buf = (char*)malloc(10000000);

    ret = read(fd, buf, 10000000);
    if (ret == -1) {
        printf("Error reading: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    } else {
        printf("bytes read: %d\n", ret);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
gcc nonblock.c -o nonblock
./nonblock 
non block is set
bytes read: 10000000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opening any (device) file in nonblocking mode does not mean you never need to wait for it.

O_NONBLOCK just says return EAGAIN if there is no data available.

Obviously, the urandom driver always considers to have data available, but isn't necessarily fast to deliver it.

Answer (score 4):

`/dev/urandom` is [non-blocking by design](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html):

> When read, the `/dev/random` device will only return random bytes
>          within the estimated number of bits of noise in the entropy pool.
>          `/dev/random` should be suitable for uses that need very high quality
>          randomness such as one-time pad or key generation.  When the entropy
>          pool is empty, reads from `/dev/random` will block until additional
>          environmental noise is gathered.
>
> A read from the `/dev/urandom` device will not block waiting for more
>          entropy.  As a result, if there is not sufficient entropy in the
>          entropy pool, the returned values are theoretically vulnerable to a
>          cryptographic attack on the algorithms used by the driver.

If you replace it with `/dev/random`, your program  should produce a different result.

Comment: read is definitely blocking in the example. It takes some seconds before read returns and it does not return E_AGAIN which I would expect on non-blocking file io.

Comment: @user2700328 That's how long it takes for the rng to generate 10MB of random data. O_NONBLOCK doesn't help you with that.

Answer (score -1):

In Linux, it is not possible to open regular files in non blocking mode. You have to use the AIO interface to read from /dev/urandom in non blocking mode.

Comment: `/dev/urandom` isn't a regular file.